# При загрузке из .plist переменная возвращает 0

Tags: xcode

почему при загрузке i7 выдаёт 0 ?

```
-(NSString *)getFilePath
{    
  //--пробую сохранить переменную
    NSArray *myAllPass = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[myAllPass objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"saved.plist"];
}

-(void)saveData;
{
 //сохраняю переменную
      // можно создать новую переменную и туда влить путь для удобства
    NSMutableDictionary *myPlistData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[self getFilePath]];
    //[self getFilePath] имееться в виду myAllPass
    [myPlistData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:step] forKey:@"int_key"]; //step - нужное значение, не 0
    [myPlistData writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
}

-(void)loadData;
{
//загружаю переменную
    NSMutableDictionary *loadDataValue = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[self getFilePath]];
    //по ключу в переменную
    int i7 = [[loadDataValue objectForKey:@"int_key"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"%i",i7);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При первой попытке сохранить данные в saveData myPlistData не будет существовать (так как файл ранее не был создан). Сделайте банальную проверку:

```
-(void)saveData;
{
    //сохраняю переменную
    // можно создать новую переменную и туда влить путь для удобства
    NSMutableDictionary *myPlistData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self getFilePath]];
    if (myPlistData == nil) {
        myPlistData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    //[self getFilePath] имееться в виду myAllPass
    [myPlistData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:step] forKey:@"int_key"]; //step - нужное значение, не 0
    [myPlistData writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, сохраняет теперь и загружает как надо)))